# How can I design a circuit that gives a logical output according to the threshold voltage?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

How can I perform the event in the image I uploaded?What should be in the control block?An ic ?or a small circuit?Note:Voltage in the node1 (supply of ctrl_block) is not constant.It can change between 0 volts and 20 volts.
[image]

Comment: You're looking for a *comparator* with push-pull outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The main component you are looking for is a *comparator*.  It has two inputs, and compares the voltage on each.  Depending on which of the inputs is the higher voltage, it outputs high or low.

There are many different comparators with different specifications, so you need to find one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on accuracy, very simple method without additional power supply is to supply Out directly from Node1. This of course requires low Node1 impedance (strong signal) to cover all Out power requirement + suppling this circuit (zeners...).

[image]